# Burninate [countup]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

As is the style of the time, what the heck is [countup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/countup)? There are 12 questions. They all seem like being tagged with Countup is worthless. There is no wiki.

All the questions look like I can edit away the tag with no consequences. But I don't think my fire is strong enough to burn this countryside

Comment: I got [this](http://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions/tagged/countup) when I followed the countup link (in case the destination redirects or is fixed, that gave me an ASP server error), then was told that SO is down for maintenance. From the timing, I feel like I may have just broken SO, and if that's the case... well... sorry about that.

Comment: The newest question links to a ["countUp" JavaScript library](http://inorganik.github.io/countUp.js/) and a couple of the other questions do appear to be about that. The reset are just about "counting" and definitely shouldn't be using that tag.

Comment: Ah, I missed those ones about the library. There were those silly questions with Countup/count down that I saw and I was like wtf is going on which this

Comment: This is the final countdown.

Comment: Only 12? Why are you asking, go and do! BTW, add countdown to the list!

Comment: @Braiam: Have fun with [tag:countdown], over 800 questions ... maybe that tag could stay

Comment: @Braiam I might even go as far as saying even a single tagged question is worthy of a Meta discussion if you're not sure.

Comment: Maybe those about the countUp Javascript library should be changed to countup-js and then just remove the rest.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to already have been [burninated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/countup).